# AngularJS ng-click does not work with controllerAs from the $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am teaching myself with Angular, and I am writing a small application for that. I am following the John Papa's Angular Style Guide, and working with **Controllers**, not **$scope** (Y030).

The problem is when I use something like ng-click="vm.doSomething()" inside a ng-view template, the event is not triggered. No messages from the console. If I use **$scope**, the application works.

To make it work, just replace "greet.configure()" by "configure()".

**Any hints?**

The complete application can be found here:

https://github.com/ajkret/spring-boot-sample/tree/controllerAs-ngView-ngClick-problem

---

Here is the routing code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').config([ '$routeProvider', routing ]);

    function routing($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/greet', {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/greet/greet.html',
            controller : 'GreetingCtrl',
            controllerAs : 'greet'
        }).when('/config', {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/config/config.html',
            controller : 'ConfigCtrl',
            controllerAs : 'config'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/greet'
        });
    }

})();
```

Here is the template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Presentation</div>
            <div class="panel-body">Here is the message of the day</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Result from Server</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>{{greet.message}}</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="greet.configure()">Configure</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('GreetingCtrl', GreetController);

    GreetController.$inject = ['GreetingService','$location','$scope'];

    function GreetController($service, $location, $scope) {
        var controller = this;
        var message;

        function get() {
            $service.get(function(greet) {
                controller.message = greet.message; 
            });
        }

        function configure() {
            $location.url('config');
        }

        $scope.configure = configure;

        // Bootstrap
        get();
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I gave up and followed the line everyone else on Angular is doing:

I gave up the $routeProvider mapping and added a div, pointing to the controller. That seems to make everything work. Could this be a bug from Angular? I don't know.

After a few restarts, reload the page, it worked.

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Presentation</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Here is the message of the day</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Result from Server</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>{{ctrl.message}}</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.configure()">Configure</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes I've had problems with cache in Chrome. I prefer to use Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$scope.configure = configure;`, for `controller.configure = configure;`

Comment: made no difference

Comment: It made no difference. In fact, expressions {{}} work just fine, but nothing works between quotes (tags).

Comment: Try this in GreetingCtrl: `function configure() {
            console.log("Inside configure");
$location.url('config');
        }`. `controller.configure = configure;`. And this in view: `ng-click="greet.configure()"`. Watch your console. If it shows "inside...", the problem is the service. You said you tried it, but can you try again?

Comment: Also, erase $scope from $injects and parameters. You're using `var controller = this`. It's not recommended to use $scope.

Answer (score 1):

When using `controllerAs` you need to bind your model data and methods to `this` in controller which you have referenced with variable `controller`

Change:

```
 $scope.configure = configure;
```

To

```
controller.configure = configure;
```

You will only need or use `$scope` for things like angular events or watches

Comment: made no difference

Comment: doesn't make sense when a little while ago you said it was working

Comment: I doubt cache had anything to do with it and you broke something else